# wine installing error

Tags: package-management, wine, update-manager

wine installing error . Please help me ..

```
E: Failed to fetch https://mirror.xeonbd.com/ubuntu-archive/pool/main/t/tiff/libtiff5_4.3.0-6ubuntu0.7_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 103.153.241.4 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://mirror.xeonbd.com/ubuntu-archive/pool/main/libx/libxml2/libxml2_2.9.13%2bdfsg-1ubuntu0.3_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 103.153.241.4 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://mirror.xeonbd.com/ubuntu-archive/pool/main/m/mesa/libgbm1_23.0.4-0ubuntu1%7e22.04.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 103.153.241.4 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://mirror.xeonbd.com/ubuntu-archive/pool/main/m/mesa/libglapi-mesa_23.0.4-0ubuntu1%7e22.04.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 103.153.241.4 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://mirror.xeonbd.com/ubuntu-archive/pool/main/m/mesa/libosmesa6_23.0.4-0ubuntu1%7e22.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 103.153.241.4 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://mirror.xeonbd.com/ubuntu-archive/pool/main/m/mesa/libosmesa6_23.0.4-0ubuntu1%7e22.04.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 103.153.241.4 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Please change mirror for you packagesources.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)